# Grab paperclip image url and pass it to scss as background image

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, coffeescript

I have an **index page** that displays a list of **images**.

On click on any of the images, i want to grab the **image_url** and pass it to my **css/scss** as **background-image**  in my **#header div**.

Below is what i have done so far:

> ## index.html.haml

```
%header
 %div#has-zoom

 %section
   - @images.each do |image|
    = image_tag image.image.url(:thumb), class: 'touched'
```

> ## image.coffee

```
$('.touched').click ->
  $('#head-zoom').addClass 'enlarge'
```

> ## image.css.scss

```
.enlarge {
          background-image: image-url(<%= image_tag image.image.url(:thumb) %>);
          height: 100vh;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
 }
```

Your assistance will be deeply and dearly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in `image.css.scss`, as `.scss` gets precompiled to `.css` file on the server side before sending it to the browser. And the interactivity you are trying is on the client side.

You could do the following:

```
$('.touched').click ->
  var image_src = $(this).attr('src')
  $('#head-zoom').addClass('enlarge')
  $('#head-zoom').css('background-image', 'url('+image_src+')')
```

And update the `.enlarge` to the following:

```
.enlarge {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: How can someone do something like this then?  

 **.css('background-image', url('<%= image_tag.image.url(:medium)')**;  

I did this, i got 

**undefined method error**. 

Pls note that the background image changes based on clicked event. i.e onClicked event background change. thanks @Dharam

Comment: `instance_variables` you set up in the `controller` are available in your `views`, but not in `.scss` files. You can use plain ruby in `.scss` files which get transformed while compiled to `.css` files. But you cannot use instance variables you set in the `controller` in `.scss` files.

Comment: I just gave your answer a vote-up. How best can i then grab the image clicked and pass it to the css. Thanks in advance. @Dharam

Comment: You cannot pass that information to the `.css` file. What you can do is to apply the `css` using javascript as I showed above.

Comment: Pls can you help me with a code sample. That might just ease my mystery. Tnx again

Comment: Its already provided above:

`$('.touched').click ->
  var image_src = $(this).attr('src')
  $('#head-zoom').addClass('enlarge')
  $('#head-zoom').css('background-image', 'url('+image_src+')')`

Comment: Yeah. It works like charm. **image_src = $(this).attr('src')**.  Thanks @Dharam for tolerating my nuance.  You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have to post what works for me using @Dharam's answer.

```
 $('.touched').click ->    #-> Gets element with the class="touched" 
 var image_src = $(this).attr('src') 
 #-> (this).attr('src') is a jquery method that grabs / returns a value.   
 #-> In my case, returns the clicked img src's value = http://localhost:3000/system/images/images/000/000/018/thumb/%2846%29.jpg?1472555101
```

Which is of course fetched from below

> ## index.html.haml
>
> ```
> = image_tag image.image.url(:thumb), class: 'touched'
> ```

That said, i can now do something like below:

```
$('#head-zoom').addClass('enlarge')
  $('#head-zoom').css('background-image', 'url('+image_src+')')
```

And that works like charm.